# Can any continuous function be re-parameterized into a differentiable function?

Tags: calculus, continuity

$|x|$ is not differentiable at zero. However, if we compose it with another function that "eases up" very gently to zero, for example, $x=t^3$, we can obtain a function $|t^3|$ which is differentiable everywhere. I imagine this as "stretching out" $|x|$ to make it smooth. It seems like any continuous function could be turned in to a differentiable function by composing it with another function, that momentarily comes down to a derivative of 0 everywhere the continuous function is not differentiable.

As I have posed it, this question has a trivial solution: $f\circ 0$ is always differentiable (even if $f$ is not continuous!). So, an additional requirement should be imposed, to fit the intuition of "stretching $f$." The function being composed should be monotonically increasing and should cover the entire domain of $f$.

Given a continuous $f(x)$, can such a $g(t)$ always be found so that $f(g(t))$ is differentiable everywhere?

Comment: The function $g(t)=t^2$ doesn't cover the entire domain of $f(x)=|x|$. It only covers $[0,\infty)$ and on the restricted domain $[0,\infty)$, $f(x)=x$ which is differentiable.

Comment: @quasi - Perhaps the OP meant $t|t|$ instead of $t^2$.

Comment: @mr_e_man: Yes, that works nicely.

Comment: @quasi That's a good point, I will change my example to $t^3$ so that it satisfies my requirements.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Vaguely related to reparameterisation of curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a broad class of functions for which this reparametrization works at a point, say the origin. A function $f$ is in $C^\alpha$, $0<\alpha$, when $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le k|x-y|^\alpha$$

Let $g_n(x):=x^n$ for $n$ odd, and $g_n(x):=\begin{cases}x^n&x\ge0\\-x^n&x<0\end{cases}$ for $n$ even.

Given $f\in C^\alpha$, let $n>1/\alpha$ , then $$\left|\frac{f(g_n(x))-f(g_n(0))}{x}\right|\le k\frac{|g_n(x)-g_n(0)|^\alpha}{|x|}= k|x|^{n\alpha-1}\to0,\quad x\to0$$ so $f(g_n(x))=f(0)+o(x)$.

This means functions like $|x|^{\beta}$, $\beta\ge0$, and the Weierstrass functions, can be smoothed out (at one point). But functions like $1/\ln|x|$, though continuous, cannot be smoothed with this reparametrization (though it can with $g(x)=sgn(x)e^{-1/|x|}$).

Answer (score 0):

if $g(x)$ is not differentiable anywhere  and there exists a monotonic differentiable function $f(x)$ then $f(g(x))$ will also not be differentiable because:
$f(g(x))$=$f(g(x))$ $\implies$ $g(x)$ = $f^{-1}f(g(x))$ since $f^{-1}$ does exist for all x due to monotonicity but by the rule that  composition of differentiable functions are differentiable (since $f$ is differentiable and monotonic $f^{-1}$ will be differentiable somewhere ($f'$ will be greater than zero somewhere)) and we know $f(g(x))$ is differentiable ) that would imply that $g(x)$ is differentiable which is a contradiction .

---

So a function differentiable nowhere will be a counter -example

Comment: As already mentioned in the OP, a counterexample to your claim occurs when $f'=0$ despite monotonicity, like with $f(x)=x^3$. Then the composition is differentiable with derivative zero and there is no contradiction because the inverse is nondifferentiable. Your point shows that this is the only way to save the day: to post-compose with a function $f$ whose derivative is zero at every point where $g'$ doesn't exist. In particularly nasty situations like when $g$ is nowhere differentiable, this will cause $f$ to lose its required monotonicity.

Comment: @Ian but that will only be one point if it is monotonic the derivative must be greater than zero somewhere and so then the contradiction will still happen dont we need that f(g(x) is differentiable everywhere?

Comment: @Ian i am assuming that g(x) is not differentiable anywhere.

Comment: Yes, if $g$ is nowhere differentiable then $f$ cannot be chosen to have zero derivative everywhere while still being monotonic.

Comment: The question was about, given $f$, finding $g$ such that $f\circ g$ is smooth. You've answered the opposite: given $g$, finding $f$ such that $f\circ g$ is smooth.